# JavaScript 'TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined' after program has ran for a period of time

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue with Deezloader (I didn't write the program, hence I am really struggling to find the cause of this problem).

The server runs fine for a period of time (maybe 10 minutes), will fetch and download songs as intended. However after the server has been running for a while, trying to download a song returns the following error in the cmd window

```
Trace: [TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined]
   at process.<anonymous> <link_to_js_app:705:11>
   at process.emit <events.js:95:17>
   at process._fatalException <node.js:295:26>
```

The code for the app can be found here: http://pastebin.com/NMmP1yET

The app will then continue to give this error until I close and reopen it - when the process repeats.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: JavaScript is not Java...

Comment: That is way too much code, narrow down to wear it happens and post that code in your question...

Comment: I wish I could narrow it down but as I said I didn't write the code - I have no idea where the issue could be

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it's in one of the locations where you are accessing `socket.downloadQueue[0]` and there isn't anything there.

Comment: Ok, any idea what I could attempt in order to fix it?